# jquery mobile listview, dynamic est data-inset for small screen devices

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a listview with `data-inset="true"`.

I wish to change it to `data-inset="false"` only for IPhone (and other small screen devices).

I have tried this:

```
$("#myListView").attr("data-inset", "false");

$("# myListView ").trigger('create');

$("# myListView ").listview("refresh");
```

with no results.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the only way you can do is this to remove the following classes.

```
$("#myListView ").attr("data-inset",false);
$("#myListView ").removeClass("ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow");
$("#myListView  li").removeClass("ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom");
```

A demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/z5rsx/

Hope that helps..